# Style SVG circle with CSS

Tags: css, svg, hover, geometry

So I have my SVG-circle.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <circle cx="168" cy="179" r="59" fill="white" />
</svg>
```

I want it to be 120% when one hover the circle. I tried both with width, height and stroke. Haven't find any solution to make the circle bigger when hovering. Any suggestions?

```
circle:hover
  {
    stroke-width:10px;
  }

circle:hover
  {
    height: 120%;
    width: 120%;
  }
```

Comment: don't know if it exists for svg, but what about css3 transform?

Comment: +1 for css transform, stroke didn't worked in the OP example because he didn't defined a `stroke` color. Use the same color as the circle fill and it will look "bigger".

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As per the SVG 1.1 specification you can't style the `r` attribute of an SVG circle using CSS https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#SVGStylingProperties. But you can do:

```
<circle cx="168" cy="179" r="59"
        fill="white" stroke="black"
        onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('r', '72');"
        onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('r', '59');"/>
```

In SVG 2, which is partially supported by some modern browsers, you can style the `r` attribute of circles using CSS. https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/styling.html#PresentationAttributes

Comment: `onmouseover="this.setAttribute('r', '72');` should work fine as well

Comment: Great solution. Even if it wasn't with CSS. Thanks!

Comment: The right answer for 2016 seems to be the one by Anshul

Answer (score 41):

Want to only use CSS? Use `line` instead of `circle`.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <style>
    .circle {
        stroke-width: 59;
        stroke-linecap: round;
    }
    .circle:hover {
        stroke-width: 71;
    }
    </style>
    <line x1="168" y1="179" x2="168" y2="179" stroke="white" class="circle" />
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rLk7rd8b/

Comment: +1 Great answer! I added `width="300" height="300"` to the `<svg>` tag to be able to see anything. Of course you cannot draw outlines of the circle this way.

Comment: Not quite circular in my experiments. :(

Comment: Here's what I see, it looks pretty circular to me. http://i.imgur.com/cKX9n3a.png @Ben, what browser are you using?

Comment: How to draw a circle pre-SVG:  Draw a div with 0 width and 0 height and a border of length r and a border radius of r.  SVG to the rescue.  Now we draw a line of length 0... 

Answer (score 33):

It can be done in CSS(3), by setting the `transform-`origin of the circle to its center and then using `scale` transformation:

```
circle {
  transform-origin: center center;
}

circle:hover {
  stroke-width: 10px;
  transform:scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
```

Comment: Yes! Plus prefixes to have it cross-browser (-o-transform-origin, -webkit-transform-origin, -moz-transform-origin, -o-transform, -webkit-transform, -moz-transform)

Comment: Slightly different situation but it worked for me to do the origin as `50% 50%` and to transition from `scale(0,0)` to `scale(1,1)`. Centered and still not specifying an absolute size.

Comment: thanks! Simple and elegant approach, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 7):

As Phillip suggested in the comment above you can do this with CSS 3 transform.

```
  circle:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(x, y);
  }
```

("-webkit" prefix is for Chrome only)

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Here's a working example with CSS transitions too: http://jsbin.com/sozewiso/2

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/#search=transform, most vendors have dropped the prefixes.  The exception (at the time of writing) being Safari, which still uses `-webkit`

Answer (score 6):

Click "Run code snippet" to test it out:

```css
.myCircle:hover {
  r: 20
}

.myCircle {
  transition: ease 1s
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
       <circle class="myCircle" cx="10" cy="10" r="5" fill="black" />
    </svg>
```

I stumbled across this page but wanted to add my own answer that I think is easiest. Apparently it doesn't work in Firefox though, which is why someone downvoted.

**Step 1:** Add a class (e.g. "myCircle") to your circle

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <circle class="myCircle" cx="168" cy="179" r="59" fill="white" />
</svg>
```

**Step 2:** In your CSS file you can use "r" as a CSS property!

```
.myCircle:hover {
  r: 100;
}
```

**Step 3 (optional):** Feel free to add a transition to make the radius grow smoothly:

```
.myCircle {
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

Comment: Latest Firefox (74) does not support styling the `r` attribute via CSS. Says "Invalid property value".

Comment: @PawełGościcki, so in FireFox you don't see the black dot when you run the code snippet above?

Comment: I see the black dot, but the `:hover` effect doesn't work.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69790400/15388872) non-zero css values must have units. If you add 'px' it's working (in Chrome 95 & Firefox 93) and according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/r) "Starting with SVG2, r is a Geometry Property meaning this attribute can also be used as a CSS property for circles." Unfortunately didn't find any concrete information on good browser support already is at the moment...

Comment: Chrome doesn't seem to recognize 'r' at all regardless of whether you 'px'.

Comment: I'm on Chrome Version 99.0.4844.83 (Official Build) (x86_64) on a Mac and the snippet above works.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rx4fr/)

You need to manipulate the radius and this can only be done via javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $("svg circle").on("mouseenter", function () {

        var oldR = $(this).attr("r");

        var newR = (((oldR*2)/100)*120)/2; // 120% width

        $(this).attr("r", newR);

    });
});
```

Comment: It won't go to original size on mouseleave

Comment: Yes, just add the code to restore the old radius on mouseleave, and this is a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you can not full custom a svg only with css. However, if you will do it won't be cross browser. 
In the past I used svg for creating a complex map and for me the solution was [rapheljs](http://raphaeljs.com/).

**EDIT:**

Using @phonicx calculus for radius i modified the code, having [something](http://jsfiddle.net/stefanz/D7yvL/1/) which is able to customize each circle ( in case if you have more ) :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <circle data-precentage='100' cx="168" cy="179" r="59" fill="red" />
   <circle data-precentage='120' cx="74" cy="100" r="59" fill="black" /> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQUERY:

```
$(function () {
  $('circle').hover(function() {
    $(this).attr('r', 100);
  }, function() {
    $(this).attr('r', 59);
  });
});
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/BCeSG/)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the stroke color:

```
circle:hover {
    stroke:white;
    stroke-width:10px;
 }
```

Comment: Tried this solution but it was buggy in Chrome. Sometimes it would work, sometimes the circle would be just an outline.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on something else and came across this question. I'm doing something similar and using greensock. I animated the scale on a couple circles using Greensock, GSAP. I needed to animate tranformOrigin and the scale property:

```
TweenMax.staggerFrom(".circle",1,{scale:0,transformOrigin:"50% 50%",ease:Bounce.easeOut}, .08);
```

Example
https://codepen.io/grmdgs/pen/RgjdPv

Greensock
https://greensock.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scale it, try with `transform: scale(1,5)`,
so you don't need to change cx,cy,r attributes.