# SVG Transform Scale in Mozilla physically moves svg from origin

Tags: css, svg, transform

Having an issue with an SVG element that I've styled with some CSS transforms.

In Mozilla - when you hover on an icon it physically moves the icon from its original position out to the bottom and to the right. From what I've been able to see, it looks like the `transform: scale(1.25)` is causing the issue but `-moz-transform-origin` isn't helping either.

Not sure how to make each icon stay in position on hover but still give a magnifying effect with transform

You can visit the site here [www2.picofemto.com](http://www2.picofemto.com)

**SVG:**

```
<svg height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 853.5 859.6" enable-background="new 0 0 853.5 859.6" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
                      <a class="icon" id="guy-in-mri-or-washing-machine" xlink:href="#">
                        <path d="M197.3,416.8c36-17.6,50.9-61,33.3-97c-17.6-35.9-61-50.9-97-33.2c-36,17.6-50.9,61-33.3,97  C117.9,419.5,161.4,434.3,197.3,416.8z" class="linked-circle"/>
                        <g class="icon-group">
                        <rect x="107.7" y="361.2" fill="#FFFFFF" width="69.2" height="6.5"/>
                        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M162,347.6c0-4.5,3.7-8.2,8.2-8.2c4.5,0,8.2,3.7,8.2,8.2c0,4.5-3.7,8.2-8.2,8.2   C165.6,355.8,162,352.1,162,347.6z"/>
                        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M151.5,339.1H124l-16.3,2.5v14.2l8.2,0c-0.7-1.1-1.1-2.3-1.1-3.6c0-3.8,3.1-6.9,6.9-6.9h15l12.2-2.5   l0.7,3.2l-12.5,2.6h-15.4c-2,0-3.6,1.6-3.6,3.6c0,2,1.6,3.6,3.6,3.6l29.8,0c4.6,0,8.3-3.7,8.3-8.3   C159.8,342.9,156.1,339.1,151.5,339.1z"/>
                        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M165.7,385.1c18.3,0,33.2-14.9,33.2-33.2c0-18.3-14.9-33.2-33.2-33.2c-12,0-22.5,6.4-28.3,15.9h13.9   c3.9-3.3,9-5.3,14.5-5.3c12.5,0,22.6,10.1,22.6,22.6c0,12.5-10.1,22.6-22.6,22.6c-3.5,0-6.9-0.8-9.8-2.3h-16.5   C145.5,380,155,385.1,165.7,385.1z"/>
                        <g>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M165.7,300.4c-22.7,0-42,14.8-48.7,35.2l6.3-1l10.3,0c6.2-11.4,18.2-19.2,32.1-19.2    c20.2,0,36.5,16.3,36.5,36.5c0,20.2-16.3,36.5-36.5,36.5c-12.7,0-23.8-6.5-30.4-16.2h-16.8c7.9,18.2,26,31,47.1,31    c28.4,0,51.4-23,51.4-51.4C217.1,323.4,194.1,300.4,165.7,300.4z M177.3,312.1c-0.2,0.7-0.8,1.2-1.6,1.2c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4-0.1    c-6.3-1.6-12.9-1.6-19.2,0c-0.9,0.2-1.8-0.3-2-1.2c-0.2-0.9,0.3-1.8,1.2-2c6.8-1.7,14-1.7,20.8,0    C177,310.4,177.6,311.2,177.3,312.1z"/>
                        </g>
                      </g>
                      </a>

                        <a class="icon" id="gattaca" xlink:href="#">
                          <path class="linked-path" d="M655.1,248.3c29.8-14.6,42.1-50.5,27.5-80.3c-14.6-29.8-50.5-42.1-80.3-27.5c-29.8,14.6-42.1,50.5-27.5,80.3  C589.4,250.6,625.3,262.9,655.1,248.3z"/>
                            <g class="icon-group">
                            <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M620.4,205.7H637c-1.4,2-3.1,3.6-4.6,4.8c-2.6,2-4.8,2.8-4.9,2.9c-0.2,0.1-1.2,0.5-2.7,1.3c0,0,0,0,0,0    c-1.7,0.9-3.9,2.3-6.1,4.4c-4.4,4-8.7,10.4-8.7,20h7.1c0-0.6,0-1.2,0.1-1.8h23.2c0,0.6,0.1,1.2,0.1,1.8h7.1c0-9.6-4.3-16-8.7-20    c-1.7,1.3-3.3,2.3-4.5,2.9l-0.2,0.1c-0.7,0.4-1.3,0.7-1.8,0.9c1.6,1.2,3.2,2.8,4.7,4.9h-16.7c1.4-2.1,3.1-3.7,4.7-4.9    c2.5-1.9,4.7-2.8,4.9-2.9c0.2-0.1,1.2-0.5,2.7-1.3c0,0,0,0,0,0c1.7-0.9,3.9-2.3,6.2-4.4c4.4-4,8.7-10.4,8.7-20    c0-9.6-4.3-16-8.7-20c-2.7,2-5.1,3.3-6.5,3.9c1.6,1.2,3.2,2.8,4.7,4.9h-16.7c1.6-2.4,3.6-4.2,5.4-5.4c0.9-0.6,1.8-1.1,2.4-1.5    l2.4-1.1c1.2-0.5,4-1.9,6.9-4.3c4.8-3.9,10-10.6,10-21.2h-7.1c0,0.7-0.1,1.3-0.1,1.9h-23.1c-0.1-0.6-0.1-1.2-0.1-1.9h-7.1    c0,9.6,4.3,16,8.7,20c2.7-2,5.1-3.3,6.5-3.9c-1.5-1.2-3.2-2.8-4.6-4.8H637c-3.7,5.4-9.1,7.5-9.5,7.7c-0.7,0.3-17.6,6.7-17.6,25.7    c0,9.6,4.3,16,8.7,20c1.4-1.1,2.9-2.1,4.5-2.9c0.8-0.4,1.5-0.8,2-1C623.5,209.4,621.9,207.8,620.4,205.7z M639.9,154.5    c-0.3,1.3-0.7,2.6-1.3,3.7h-19.8c-0.5-1.1-0.9-2.4-1.3-3.7H639.9z M617.6,234.4c0.3-1.3,0.7-2.6,1.2-3.7h19.8    c0.5,1.1,0.9,2.4,1.2,3.7H617.6z M640.3,196.3h-23.1c-0.1-0.6-0.1-1.2-0.1-1.9c0-0.6,0-1.2,0.1-1.8h23.2c0,0.6,0.1,1.2,0.1,1.8    C640.4,195.1,640.3,195.7,640.3,196.3z M638.6,186c0.5,1.1,0.9,2.4,1.2,3.7h-22.3c0.3-1.3,0.7-2.6,1.2-3.7H638.6z M618.8,202.9    c-0.5-1.1-0.9-2.4-1.2-3.7h22.3c-0.3,1.3-0.7,2.6-1.3,3.7H618.8z"/>
                          </g>
                        </a>
                        <a class="icon" id="guy-with-epcot-center-head" xlink:href="#">
                          <path class="linked-path" d="M753.4,401.2c16.7,34,2.5,75.1-31.5,91.8c-34,16.6-75.1,2.5-91.8-31.5c-16.7-34-2.6-75.1,31.5-91.8  C695.7,353.1,736.8,367.1,753.4,401.2z"/>

                          <g class="icon-group">
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M697,386.4c0.1-0.4,0.2-0.9,0.5-1.2c0.9-1.2,2.7-1.5,4-0.5c0.9,0.7,1.3,1.7,1.2,2.7L697,386.4z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M710.2,391.9c0.4,0.2,0.8,0.4,1.2,0.7c0,1.7,0,3.4,0,5.1c-0.4,0.1-0.7,0.2-0.9,0.4   c-1.5-1.1-2.9-2.2-4.4-3.3c0-0.4,0-0.8-0.2-1.2C707.3,393.1,708.7,392.6,710.2,391.9z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M703.6,392.1c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0c-0.6-1.2-1.2-2.3-1.8-3.4c0.9,0.2,1.8,0.4,2.7,0.7   c1.6,0.5,3.1,1.1,4.4,1.7c-1.2,0.5-2.5,0.9-3.7,1.4C704.6,392.3,704.1,392.1,703.6,392.1z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M698.8,388.3c0.3,0,0.7,0.1,1,0.1c0.8,1.4,1.6,2.8,2.3,4.2c-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.5-0.6,0.7   c-1.9-0.3-3.8-0.5-5.6-0.7c0-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.4-1.2C696.7,390.6,697.9,389.5,698.8,388.3z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M694.5,390.6c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-1-0.2c-0.4,0-0.7,0.1-1,0.2c-0.9-0.9-1.8-1.7-2.8-2.6   c2.5-0.1,5.1-0.1,7.6,0.1C696.4,389.1,695.5,389.9,694.5,390.6z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M683.2,391.5c-0.7,0-1.2,0.3-1.6,0.6c-1.5-0.6-2.9-1.3-4.3-2c1.6-0.6,3.3-1,5-1.3c0.8-0.1,1.7-0.3,2.6-0.4   C684.4,389.4,683.8,390.4,683.2,391.5z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M674.4,395.6c0.3-1.5,0.5-3.1,0.8-4.6c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5-0.2c1.7,0.9,3.5,1.7,5.3,2.5   c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.6c-1.9,0.8-3.8,1.4-5.5,2.4C675.2,396,674.9,395.7,674.4,395.6z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M673.1,395.5c-0.7,0.1-1.3,0.5-1.6,1.1c-1.2-0.2-2.4-0.5-3.7-0.7c1.8-1.6,3.7-3,5.9-4.2   C673.5,393,673.3,394.2,673.1,395.5z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M671.5,399.2c-1.3,1.2-2.5,2.4-3.8,3.6c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5,0c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c-0.4-1.6-0.8-3.2-1.2-4.8   c0.3-0.3,0.6-0.7,0.9-1c1.5,0.3,3,0.5,4.4,0.9C671.2,398.3,671.3,398.8,671.5,399.2z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M665.8,403.2c-0.5,0.4-0.8,0.9-0.9,1.5c-1.3,0.3-2.6,0.7-3.8,1.1c1-2.4,2.3-4.5,3.8-6.5   C665.1,400.6,665.5,401.9,665.8,403.2z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M665.9,407.4c-0.4,1.8-1.1,3.6-1.8,5.4c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.4,0c-0.6,0-1,0.2-1.4,0.4c-0.8-1.2-1.7-2.3-2.6-3.5   c0.2-0.8,0.5-1.5,0.7-2.3c1.5-0.5,3-1,4.5-1.3C665,406.6,665.4,407,665.9,407.4z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M661.3,415.6c-1,0.6-2,1.4-2.9,2.1c0.1-1.5,0.2-3,0.5-4.6c0.1-0.6,0.2-1.3,0.4-1.9c0.8,1,1.5,2,2.1,3   C661.2,414.7,661.2,415.1,661.3,415.6z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M658.4,419.4c1.1-0.9,2.2-1.8,3.4-2.6c0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,1.1,0.7c0.2,1.9,0.4,3.8,0.8,5.7   c-0.6,0.2-1,0.6-1.2,1.1c-1.2-1-2.6-1.8-3.9-2.7C658.4,420.9,658.4,420.2,658.4,419.4z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M660.4,429.8c-0.8-2-1.4-4.2-1.7-6.5c1.2,0.8,2.4,1.6,3.5,2.6c0,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.4,1.1   C661.8,427.9,661.1,428.9,660.4,429.8z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M664.5,428c0.6,1.9,1.6,3.5,2.5,5.3c-0.4,0.3-0.6,0.7-0.8,1.2c-1.5-0.5-3-1.2-4.5-1.9   c-0.2-0.4-0.5-0.9-0.7-1.4c0.8-1.1,1.7-2.2,2.5-3.4C663.8,427.9,664.1,428,664.5,428z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M666.7,437c-0.5,0.8-0.9,1.6-1.3,2.5c-0.9-1.7-1.8-3.4-2.7-5c1.1,0.5,2.2,1,3.4,1.4   C666.2,436.3,666.4,436.7,666.7,437z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M668.5,437.7c0.6,0,1.1-0.2,1.4-0.4c2.2,0.7,4.4,1.2,6.5,2c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.4c-1.8,0.4-3.6,1-5.4,1.4   c-1.5,0.3-2.9,0.6-4.4,1c-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.7-0.5-1.1c0.5-1.2,1-2.3,1.7-3.4C668.1,437.7,668.3,437.7,668.5,437.7z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M712.7,402.5c1.1,1.3,2,2.9,2.7,4.4c-0.4,0.4-0.6,0.8-0.7,1.4c-3,0-6-0.2-9-0.4c0-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.9   c1.5-1.7,3.3-3.2,5.1-4.6c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.3,1.2,0.3C712.1,402.6,712.4,402.6,712.7,402.5z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M704.7,406c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3c0-2.9-0.1-5.7-0.1-8.6c0.7-0.1,1.3-0.5,1.6-1c1.4,1,2.7,2,4,3   c-0.3,0.7-0.2,1.6,0.1,2.3C707.9,402.8,706.2,404.3,704.7,406z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M701.4,395.7c-1.3,1.1-2.5,2.4-3.7,3.6c-1.2,1.2-2.6,2.1-3.9,3.2c0-2.4,0-4.8,0.3-7.3   c0.8-0.2,1.3-0.7,1.6-1.3c1.9,0.2,3.7,0.5,5.6,0.7C701.2,395,701.3,395.4,701.4,395.7z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M682.5,406c0.2-3.2,0.6-6.3,0.7-9.5c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c2.4,2.4,4.8,4.8,7.1,7.4   c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.2,0.7c-2.5,0.5-4.8,1.6-7.3,2C682.8,406.3,682.6,406.1,682.5,406z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M681.9,396c0,3.1-0.5,6.3-0.7,9.4c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6,0.1c-1.3-2.2-2.8-4.4-4.6-6.2   c0.3-0.5,0.4-1.1,0.3-1.7c1.6-1,3.4-1.7,5.2-2.4C681.3,395.5,681.6,395.8,681.9,396z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M674.5,414.7c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6,0.1c-1.5-2.7-3.4-5.1-5-7.7c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3   c3.1,0.2,6.2,0.8,9.4,1.1c0,0.5,0.1,0.9,0.3,1.3c-1.3,1.8-2.4,3.7-3.4,5.6C675.1,414.7,674.8,414.7,674.5,414.7z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M664.2,417.6c0.7-0.2,1.2-0.6,1.5-1.1c2.1,0.5,4.2,0.9,6.4,1.1c0.1,0.4,0.2,0.7,0.4,1   c-1.9,1.9-4.3,3.2-6.3,5.1c-0.3-0.3-0.7-0.5-1.2-0.6C664.6,421.3,664.4,419.4,664.2,417.6z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M673.5,419.4c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.2,0.9,0.2c0.1,2.1,0.3,4.2,0.6,6.3c-0.6,0.3-1,0.8-1.2,1.4   c-2.3-0.5-4.6-0.9-6.9-1.4c0-0.3,0-0.7,0-1C668.8,422.9,671.4,421.5,673.5,419.4z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M666.4,427.2c2.4,0.5,4.8,1,7.2,1.5c0,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.8c-1.4,1.2-2.9,2.4-4.3,3.6   c-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.3-1.1-0.3c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0c-0.9-1.7-1.9-3.3-2.4-5.1C666,427.6,666.2,427.4,666.4,427.2z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M709.1,416.4c-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.7,0.1c-1.4-2-2.5-4.2-4-6.2c0.6-0.3,0.9-0.7,1.2-1.2c3.1,0.3,6.1,0.5,9.2,0.4   c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.7c-1.8,2-3.4,4.2-4.9,6.4C709.9,416.5,709.5,416.4,709.1,416.4z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M695.7,414.2C695.6,414.2,695.6,414.2,695.7,414.2c-0.5-2.4-1-4.8-1.6-7.2c0.3-0.2,0.5-0.5,0.7-0.8   c2.1,0.7,4.2,1.4,6.3,1.9c0,0.5,0.1,0.9,0.3,1.3c-1.9,1.5-3.5,3.4-5.5,4.8C695.8,414.2,695.7,414.2,695.7,414.2z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M693.7,415.2c-3.4-2.3-7.1-4.2-10.8-6c0.2-0.4,0.3-0.9,0.3-1.4c2.4-0.5,4.6-1.5,7-2c0.3,0.9,1,1.7,2.3,1.7   c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0c0.6,2.4,1.1,4.7,1.5,7.1C694.1,414.8,693.9,415,693.7,415.2z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M706.7,418.9c0,0.5,0.1,1.1,0.4,1.5c-1.4,2-2.6,4.1-4.2,6c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2,0c-0.4,0-0.7,0.1-1,0.2   c-1.3-2.8-2.9-5.4-4.3-8.1c0.4-0.4,0.6-1,0.7-1.5C701,417.4,703.9,418.1,706.7,418.9z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M669.4,453.5c-0.2-3.8-1-7.1-2.2-10.1c1.2-0.3,2.4-0.6,3.7-0.8c2.1-0.4,4.1-1.2,6.2-1.6   c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.8,0.6C675.2,445.6,672.2,449.5,669.4,453.5z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M667.8,465.2c-0.4,1.5-2.5,7.1-6.3,12.2h41.3c0.9-4.4,2.5-16.4,6.7-17.6c5.6-1.6,12.8,0.7,14.2-5.1   c0.5-2-0.7-3.3-0.4-5.6c0.2-1.4,3-2.9,0.6-4.7c1.2-0.7,2-1.6,1.7-2.6c-0.1-0.6-0.3-1.7-0.4-2.3c-0.4-1.4,1.6-2.1,2.5-2.4   c0,0,0,0,0,0c0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.7-0.3c2.4-1.3,1.7-3.2,0.4-5l-5.4-8.4c-0.2-0.6-0.4-1.3-0.4-1.9c-0.2-2,1-2.7,1.2-4.3   c0.2-1.9-0.2-3.7-0.8-5.4c-1.6-0.3-3.2-0.7-4.6-1.4c-0.4,0.5-1,0.8-1.8,0.8c-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-0.9-0.2c-1.9,2-3.4,4.2-5,6.5   c0.9,1.5,0.2,3.9-2,3.9c-0.4,0-0.7-0.1-1-0.2c-1.3,1.9-2.5,3.9-3.9,5.7c1.5,1.3,1,4.5-1.5,4.5c-2.2,0-2.9-2.3-2.1-3.8   c-1.3-2.9-3-5.6-4.4-8.4c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.1c-1.7,0-2.5-1.4-2.4-2.7c-3.6-2.4-7.4-4.4-11.3-6.3c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.2-1.1,0.2   c-0.4,0-0.8-0.1-1.1-0.2c-1.3,1.8-2.3,3.6-3.3,5.6c0.7,1.1,0.5,2.9-0.8,3.6c0.1,2.1,0.3,4.3,0.6,6.4c2.6,0.2,2.9,4,0.7,4.8   c0.6,2.1,1.2,4.2,1.9,6.2c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c3.1,0,3.2,4.5,0.4,4.9c-3.1,4.9-6.6,9.4-9.9,14.1c0,1.4-0.2,2.9-0.4,4.5   C668.8,462.1,668.2,463.6,667.8,465.2z M681.4,426.5c-0.4-2.5-0.1-4.7,0.8-6.5c0.5-0.9,1.1-1.7,1.8-2.3c0.8-0.6,1.6-1,2.6-1.2   c0.3,0,0.5-0.1,0.8-0.1c0.9,0,1.8,0.3,2.5,0.8c0.7,0.4,1.3,1,1.8,1.8c0.3,0.4,0.5,0.9,0.8,1.4h-2.1c-0.8-1.2-1.8-2.1-3-2.1   c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5,0c-2.6,0.4-4.3,3.4-3.6,7.8c0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5c0.3,1.2,0.8,2.4,1.5,3.5c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5   c0.8,0.9,1.6,1.7,2.4,2.6c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.6c0.7,1,1.4,2.5,2.8,2.5c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3,0c0.3,0,0.6-0.1,0.7-0.2   c0.5-0.2,0.4-0.6,0.1-1.2h1.9c0.1,0.5,0.2,1.1-0.1,1.7c-0.2,0.6-0.7,1-1.3,1.3l0,0c-0.2,0.1-0.7,0.3-1.3,0.3c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4,0   c-1,0-1.9-0.4-2.7-1.1c-0.5-0.5-0.9-1.1-1.3-1.6c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5c-0.4-0.4-0.8-0.8-1.2-1.3   c-0.4-0.4-0.8-0.8-1.2-1.3l0-0.1l0-0.1c-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.4-0.6c-0.8-1.3-1.4-2.7-1.7-4.1l0,0l0,0   C681.4,426.9,681.4,426.7,681.4,426.5z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M720.5,403.6c0.5,1.2,1,2.5,1.5,3.9c0.3,0.9,0.6,1.9,1,2.9c-1.2-0.3-2.5-0.6-3.6-1.1c0.1-0.7,0-1.4-0.3-2   C719.6,406.1,720,404.8,720.5,403.6z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M702.3,410.3c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.2c1.7,2.1,2.9,4.5,4.4,6.7c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.3   c-3.1-0.8-6.1-1.6-9.2-2c-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.6-0.8C699,413.4,700.5,411.7,702.3,410.3z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M676.7,438c-2-0.7-4-1.2-6-1.9c0.2-0.7,0.2-1.5-0.2-2.2c1.4-1.2,2.8-2.4,4.2-3.6c0.2,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.8,0.3   c0.6,2.2,1.2,4.3,2,6.5C677.2,437.4,676.9,437.7,676.7,438z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M666,415.2c0-0.7-0.3-1.4-0.8-1.9c0.7-1.8,1.5-3.6,1.9-5.5c0,0,0,0,0,0c0.2,0,0.3,0,0.5,0   c1.7,2.6,3.6,5,5.1,7.7c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.5-0.5,0.8C670.1,416,668.1,415.6,666,415.2z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M669.6,405.5c0.1-0.7-0.2-1.5-0.7-2c1.2-1.1,2.3-2.2,3.5-3.3c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.3,1.2,0.3   c0.5,0,0.8-0.1,1.2-0.3c1.7,1.8,3.2,3.8,4.4,6c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.3-0.3,0.5C675.7,406.3,672.6,405.7,669.6,405.5z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M692.8,395.2c-0.3,2.4-0.3,4.8-0.3,7.3c-0.4,0-0.8,0.1-1.1,0.3c-2.1-2.4-4.4-4.6-6.6-6.9   c0.5-0.4,0.8-1,0.9-1.7c1.8-0.3,3.6-0.5,5.5-0.7C691.4,394.4,691.9,395,692.8,395.2z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M702.6,396.9c0,2.9,0.1,5.9,0.1,8.8c-0.7,0.2-1.2,0.6-1.4,1.2c-2.1-0.6-4.2-1.3-6.3-2   c0-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.4-1.3c1.2-1,2.5-1.9,3.7-3c1.4-1.3,2.6-2.7,4-3.9C702.4,396.8,702.5,396.9,702.6,396.9z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M685.5,393c-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.9-1-1.2c0.7-1.2,1.4-2.4,2-3.6c0.4,0,0.8-0.1,1.3-0.1c1.2,1.1,2.4,2.2,3.6,3.3   c-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.5-0.3,0.8C689.2,392.4,687.4,392.7,685.5,393z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M712.6,397.8c0.1-1.4,0-2.8,0-4.3c2.3,1.7,4.2,3.7,5.7,6.1c-1.5-0.3-2.9-0.5-4.4-0.5   C713.7,398.5,713.3,398,712.6,397.8z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M717.1,406.3c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5,0c-0.8-1.6-1.8-3.2-2.9-4.6c0.3-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.4-1.3   c1.7,0.1,3.4,0.4,5.1,0.7c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.5,1c-0.7,1.4-1.2,2.9-1.8,4.3C717.8,406.3,717.4,406.3,717.1,406.3z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M722.9,403.6l-2.6-5.1c0.4-0.2,0.8-0.3,1.3-0.3c1.5,0,2.8,1.3,2.8,2.9C724.4,402.2,723.8,403.1,722.9,403.6   z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M709.2,389.5c0.2-0.4,0.5-0.7,0.9-1c1.3-0.9,3-0.5,3.9,0.9c0.6,0.9,0.6,2.1,0.2,3L709.2,389.5z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M684.3,385.4c0.5-1.4,2.2-2.2,3.7-1.6c1,0.4,1.7,1.3,1.9,2.3l-5.7,0.6C684,386.3,684.1,385.9,684.3,385.4z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M671.7,388.9c0.1-1.5,1.5-2.7,3.1-2.6c1.1,0.1,2,0.8,2.4,1.7l-5.3,2.2C671.7,389.8,671.6,389.4,671.7,388.9   z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M661.9,397.1c-0.5-1.5,0.3-3.1,1.8-3.6c1.1-0.4,2.2-0.1,2.9,0.6l-4,4.1C662.3,397.9,662,397.5,661.9,397.1z   "/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M655.9,410.2c-1.1-1-1.2-2.8-0.1-4c0.8-0.8,1.9-1.1,2.8-0.9l-1.6,5.5C656.7,410.8,656.3,410.5,655.9,410.2z   "/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M653.7,420.3c0.4-1,1.3-1.7,2.3-1.9l0.6,5.7c-0.4,0.1-0.9,0-1.3-0.1C653.9,423.4,653.1,421.8,653.7,420.3z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M658.5,430.3l2.1,5.3c-0.4,0.2-0.8,0.2-1.3,0.2c-1.5-0.1-2.6-1.6-2.5-3.1   C656.9,431.6,657.6,430.7,658.5,430.3z"/>
                          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M664.4,445.2c-1.5,0-2.7-1.4-2.7-3c0-1.1,0.7-2.1,1.6-2.5l2.4,5.2C665.3,445.1,664.9,445.2,664.4,445.2z"/>
                          </g>
                        </a>

                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#C6C6C6" d="M560.3,347.9c-26,12.8-57.5,2-70.2-24.1c-12.7-26-2-57.5,24.1-70.2  c26-12.7,57.5-1.9,70.2,24.1C597.1,303.7,586.3,335.2,560.3,347.9z"/>
                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#C6C6C6" d="M606,76.7c-7.3-14.9-25.2-21.1-40.1-13.8c-14.9,7.3-21.1,25.2-13.8,40.1  c7.3,14.9,25.2,21.1,40.1,13.8C607.2,109.5,613.3,91.6,606,76.7z"/>
                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#C6C6C6" d="M483.6,674.7c28.5-14,40.3-48.4,26.4-76.9c-14-28.5-48.4-40.3-76.9-26.4  c-28.5,13.9-40.3,48.4-26.4,76.9C420.6,676.8,455.1,688.7,483.6,674.7z"/>
                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#C6C6C6" d="M203.1,653.3c23.6-11.5,33.3-40,21.8-63.6c-11.5-23.5-40-33.3-63.5-21.8  c-23.6,11.5-33.3,40-21.8,63.6C151.1,655.1,179.6,664.8,203.1,653.3z"/>
                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#C6C6C6" d="M400.3,831.7c-4.7-9.6-16.3-13.6-25.9-8.9c-9.6,4.7-13.6,16.3-8.9,25.9  c4.7,9.6,16.3,13.6,25.9,8.9C401.1,852.9,405,841.3,400.3,831.7z"/>
                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#C6C6C6" d="M594.3,417.4c15.5-7.6,21.9-26.3,14.3-41.8c-7.6-15.5-26.3-21.9-41.8-14.3  c-15.5,7.6-21.9,26.3-14.4,41.8C560,418.6,578.8,425,594.3,417.4z"/>

                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#C6C6C6" d="M61,581.9c14.1-6.9,19.9-24,13-38.1c-6.9-14.2-23.9-20-38.1-13c-14.1,6.9-20,24-13.1,38.1  C29.8,583,46.9,588.8,61,581.9z"/>
                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#C6C6C6" d="M365.4,96c13-6.4,18.4-22.1,12.1-35.1c-6.4-13-22.1-18.4-35.2-12c-13,6.4-18.4,22.1-12,35.1  C336.7,97,352.4,102.4,365.4,96z"/>
                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#C6C6C6" d="M298.5,159.9c11.2-5.4,15.8-19,10.4-30.1c-5.5-11.2-19-15.8-30.1-10.3  c-11.1,5.5-15.8,19-10.3,30.1C273.8,160.7,287.3,165.3,298.5,159.9z"/>
                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#C6C6C6" d="M608.8,748.5c5.6-2.7,7.9-9.5,5.2-15.1c-2.8-5.6-9.5-7.9-15.1-5.2c-5.6,2.7-7.9,9.4-5.1,15  C596.5,748.9,603.2,751.2,608.8,748.5z"/>
                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#C6C6C6" d="M810.1,608.7c26-12.7,36.8-44.2,24.1-70.2c-12.7-26.1-44.2-36.9-70.2-24.1  c-26.1,12.8-36.9,44.2-24.1,70.2C752.6,610.7,784,621.5,810.1,608.7z"/>
                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#C6C6C6" d="M771.4,238.9c16.1-7.9,22.8-27.4,14.9-43.5c-7.9-16.1-27.4-22.8-43.5-14.9  c-16.1,7.9-22.8,27.4-14.9,43.5C735.8,240.1,755.3,246.7,771.4,238.9z"/>
                        <path id="_x23__2_37_" opacity="0.5" fill="#737373" d="M357.9,465.8c-19.4-39.7-3-87.6,36.7-107c39.7-19.4,87.6-3,107,36.7  c19.4,39.7,3,87.6-36.7,107C425.2,521.9,377.3,505.5,357.9,465.8z M297.4,478.7c26.1-12.7,36.9-44.2,24.1-70.2  c-12.7-26.1-44.2-36.8-70.2-24.1c-26,12.7-36.8,44.2-24.1,70.2C239.9,480.7,271.3,491.4,297.4,478.7z M346.9,307  c29.8-14.6,42.1-50.6,27.5-80.3c-14.6-29.8-50.5-42.1-80.3-27.5c-29.8,14.6-42.1,50.5-27.5,80.3C281.2,309.2,317.2,321.5,346.9,307z   M532.6,168.7c-9.1-18.6-31.6-26.3-50.2-17.2c-18.6,9.1-26.3,31.6-17.2,50.2c9.1,18.6,31.6,26.4,50.2,17.2  C534,209.8,541.7,187.3,532.6,168.7z M102.8,476.1c16.1-7.9,22.8-27.3,14.9-43.5c-7.9-16.1-27.3-22.8-43.5-14.9  c-16.1,7.9-22.8,27.4-14.9,43.5C67.2,477.3,86.7,484,102.8,476.1z M82.1,294.6c16.2-7.9,22.8-27.4,14.9-43.6  c-7.9-16.2-27.4-22.9-43.6-14.9c-16.1,7.9-22.8,27.4-14.9,43.6C46.4,295.9,65.9,302.5,82.1,294.6z M721.1,744.6  c14.9-7.3,21.1-25.3,13.8-40.1c-7.3-14.9-25.2-21-40.1-13.7c-14.9,7.3-21,25.2-13.7,40.1C688.3,745.7,706.3,751.8,721.1,744.6z   M377,780.8c25.4-12.5,36-43.1,23.5-68.6c-12.4-25.4-43.1-35.9-68.5-23.5c-25.4,12.4-36,43.1-23.5,68.5  C320.9,782.7,351.6,793.2,377,780.8z M772.1,276.2c-24.8,12.2-35.1,42.1-23,67c12.2,24.8,42.2,35.1,67,23c24.9-12.2,35.1-42.2,23-67  C826.9,274.3,796.9,264,772.1,276.2z M199.2,121.6c10.5-5.1,14.8-17.7,9.7-28.2c-5.1-10.5-17.8-14.8-28.2-9.6  c-10.4,5.1-14.8,17.7-9.7,28.2C176.1,122.3,188.7,126.6,199.2,121.6z M233.2,273.5c10.5-5.2,14.9-17.9,9.7-28.4  c-5.1-10.5-17.9-14.9-28.4-9.7c-10.6,5.2-14.9,17.9-9.8,28.4C209.9,274.3,222.6,278.7,233.2,273.5z M291.3,662.4  c11.1-5.4,15.7-18.8,10.2-29.8c-5.4-11.1-18.8-15.7-29.9-10.3c-11.1,5.4-15.7,18.8-10.3,29.9C266.8,663.3,280.2,667.8,291.3,662.4z"/>
                        <path id="_x23__3_37_" opacity="0.5" fill="#2D2D2D" d="M8.4,405.8c-4.9-9.9-0.7-21.9,9.2-26.8c9.9-4.9,21.9-0.7,26.8,9.2  c4.9,9.9,0.7,21.9-9.2,26.8C25.2,419.8,13.2,415.7,8.4,405.8z M649.4,697.6c31.6-15.5,44.7-53.7,29.2-85.3  c-15.5-31.6-53.6-44.7-85.3-29.3c-31.6,15.5-44.7,53.7-29.2,85.3C579.6,699.9,617.8,713,649.4,697.6z M626.7,540.3  c-4.3-8.7-14.7-12.3-23.4-8.1c-8.7,4.3-12.3,14.7-8,23.4c4.3,8.7,14.7,12.2,23.4,8C627.4,559.4,631,548.9,626.7,540.3z M309.2,793.1  c-4.2-8.7-14.8-12.3-23.4-8c-8.7,4.2-12.3,14.7-8,23.4c4.2,8.7,14.7,12.3,23.4,8C309.8,812.2,313.4,801.7,309.2,793.1z M498.4,107.2  c-4.2-8.6-14.7-12.3-23.4-8c-8.6,4.2-12.2,14.8-8,23.4c4.2,8.7,14.7,12.3,23.4,8C499.1,126.3,502.7,115.9,498.4,107.2z M679.9,338.8  c18-8.8,25.4-30.5,16.6-48.5c-8.8-18-30.5-25.4-48.5-16.7c-18,8.8-25.4,30.5-16.6,48.5C640.2,340.2,661.9,347.7,679.9,338.8z   M192,219.8c23-11.2,32.4-39,21.2-61.9c-11.2-22.9-38.9-32.4-61.8-21.2c-23,11.2-32.5,38.9-21.2,61.9  C141.4,221.5,169.1,231,192,219.8z M729.2,277.5c6.9-3.4,9.7-11.6,6.3-18.5c-3.4-6.8-11.6-9.7-18.5-6.3c-6.8,3.4-9.7,11.6-6.3,18.5  C714.1,278,722.4,280.8,729.2,277.5z"/>
                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#5E5E5E" d="M515.7,515.3c-11.2-22.9-1.8-50.7,21.2-61.9c22.9-11.2,50.7-1.7,61.9,21.3  c11.2,22.9,1.7,50.6-21.2,61.9C554.6,547.7,526.9,538.2,515.7,515.3z"/>
                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#5E5E5E" d="M323.1,592.9c22.9-11.2,32.4-38.9,21.2-61.9c-11.2-23-38.9-32.5-61.9-21.2  c-22.9,11.2-32.5,38.9-21.2,61.9C272.4,594.6,300.1,604.1,323.1,592.9z"/>
                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#5E5E5E" d="M550.9,840.4c16.2-7.9,22.8-27.3,14.9-43.5c-7.9-16.1-27.3-22.8-43.5-14.9  c-16.1,7.9-22.8,27.3-14.9,43.5C515.3,841.6,534.8,848.3,550.9,840.4z"/>


                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#5E5E5E" d="M158.2,555.4c21.1-10.3,29.8-35.7,19.5-56.8c-10.3-21.1-35.8-29.8-56.9-19.5  c-21.1,10.3-29.8,35.8-19.5,56.9C111.6,557,137.1,565.7,158.2,555.4z"/>
                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#5E5E5E" d="M111.3,668.9c16.9-8.2,23.9-28.6,15.6-45.5c-8.2-16.9-28.6-23.8-45.5-15.6  c-16.9,8.3-23.9,28.6-15.6,45.5C74,670.1,94.4,677.1,111.3,668.9z"/>
                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#5E5E5E" d="M544.4,753.1c20.5-10,28.9-34.7,18.9-55.2c-10-20.5-34.7-28.9-55.2-18.9  c-20.4,10-28.9,34.7-18.9,55.2C499.2,754.7,524,763.1,544.4,753.1z"/>
                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#5E5E5E" d="M418.9,195.1c22.9-11.2,32.4-38.9,21.2-61.9c-11.2-22.9-38.9-32.4-61.9-21.2  c-22.9,11.2-32.4,38.9-21.2,61.9C368.3,196.8,396,206.4,418.9,195.1z"/>
                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#5E5E5E" d="M484.7,78.2c19.2-9.4,27.1-32.6,17.7-51.8c-9.4-19.2-32.6-27.1-51.8-17.8  c-19.2,9.4-27.1,32.6-17.7,51.8C442.4,79.6,465.6,87.6,484.7,78.2z"/>
                        <path id="_x23__5_37_" opacity="0.5" fill="#AFAFAF" d="M418.7,288.5c-6.7-13.6-1-30.1,12.6-36.8c13.7-6.7,30.1-1,36.8,12.6  c6.7,13.6,1,30.1-12.6,36.8C441.8,307.8,425.3,302.2,418.7,288.5z M669.4,135.2c6.7,13.7,23.1,19.3,36.8,12.6  c13.7-6.7,19.3-23.1,12.6-36.8c-6.7-13.6-23.2-19.3-36.8-12.6C668.3,105.1,662.7,121.6,669.4,135.2z M280.9,58.1  c-7.3-14.9-25.2-21-40.1-13.8c-14.9,7.3-21.1,25.2-13.7,40.1c7.3,14.9,25.2,21.1,40.1,13.8C282,91,288.2,73,280.9,58.1z   M694.1,569.9c16.2-7.9,22.8-27.3,14.9-43.5c-7.9-16.1-27.3-22.8-43.5-14.9c-16.1,7.9-22.8,27.4-14.9,43.5  C658.5,571.2,678,577.8,694.1,569.9z M252.9,785.3c32.8-16.1,46.4-55.7,30.4-88.6c-16.1-32.9-55.8-46.5-88.6-30.4  c-32.9,16.1-46.5,55.8-30.4,88.7C180.3,787.8,220,801.4,252.9,785.3z M235.2,533.4c10-4.9,14.1-16.9,9.2-26.9  c-4.9-10-16.9-14.1-26.8-9.2c-10,4.9-14.1,16.9-9.2,26.8C213.2,534.2,225.2,538.3,235.2,533.4z M462.4,790.4  c10.5-5.1,14.9-17.9,9.8-28.4c-5.1-10.6-17.9-14.9-28.4-9.8c-10.5,5.1-14.9,17.9-9.7,28.5C439.2,791.2,451.9,795.6,462.4,790.4z   M365.8,658.2c14.2-7,20.2-24.2,13.2-38.5c-7-14.3-24.2-20.2-38.5-13.2c-14.3,7-20.2,24.2-13.2,38.5  C334.2,659.3,351.5,665.2,365.8,658.2z M263.8,205.6c5.6-2.7,7.9-9.5,5.2-15.1c-2.7-5.6-9.5-7.9-15.1-5.1c-5.6,2.7-7.9,9.5-5.2,15.1  C251.5,206,258.2,208.4,263.8,205.6z M342.7,366.8c12.1-5.9,17.1-20.6,11.2-32.7c-5.9-12.1-20.6-17.2-32.7-11.2S304,343.5,310,355.6  C315.9,367.8,330.6,372.8,342.7,366.8z M645.2,802.7c12.1-5.9,17.2-20.6,11.2-32.7c-5.9-12.2-20.6-17.1-32.7-11.2  c-12.1,5.9-17.1,20.6-11.2,32.7C618.5,803.7,633.1,808.7,645.2,802.7z M391.9,563.5c11.3-5.5,15.9-19.1,10.4-30.3  c-5.5-11.2-19.1-15.9-30.4-10.4c-11.2,5.5-15.9,19.1-10.4,30.4C367.1,564.3,380.7,569,391.9,563.5z"/>



                        <path opacity="0.5" fill="#737373" d="M825.2,459.7c16.1-7.9,22.8-27.3,14.9-43.5c-7.9-16.1-27.3-22.8-43.5-14.9  c-16.1,7.9-22.8,27.4-14.9,43.5C789.6,461,809.1,467.6,825.2,459.7z"/>
                    </svg>
```

**CSS:**

```
.svg-container {
        display: block;
        height: 900px;
        margin: auto;

        svg {width: 100%;}
        .icon,
        path { @include vendor-prefix(transition, all 300ms ease);}

        .icon {
            @include vendor-prefix(transition, all 300ms ease);
            @include vendor-prefix(transform-origin, center center);
            @include vendor-prefix(transform, scale(1));
            position:relative; 
            z-index:10; 
            > path { 
                fill: #5e5e5e; 
                stroke-width:5px; 
                stroke: #5e5e5e; 
            }

            &:hover {
                @include vendor-prefix(transform, scale(1.25));}
            &:hover ~ path {opacity: 0.2 !important;}
            &:hover > path { 
                fill: $pico-orange !important; 
                opacity: 1 !important; 
                stroke: darken($pico-orange, 10%) ; 
            }
            &:hover > g, 
            &:hover > g > path { pointer-events:none; } //otherwise hovers get interfered with
            &:hover > g > path { fill: #fff !important; }
        }
```

Comment: Could it be a similar problem to what I had here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622510/svg-nodes-in-d3-force-layout-moves-on-node-scale/

Comment: @Leo it may, but I cannot seem to get the transform-origin to actually work properly.

Comment: Did you use the vendor prefix as Delapouite suggested?

Comment: Here is where I played with it. Maybe that can help you. http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/vLXFb/1/

Comment: This doesn't work in FF. It still moves the physical position of the each circle off of its center.

Comment: You are right. Looks like a bug in FF (or the standard is not yet set, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin). I think we are both out of luck here then. :-(

Comment: You have provided a lot of code here, please consider revising your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to abandon css, but in the svg itself, the effect is achieved by wrapping the link in three groups, translating to the origin, applying the scale then returning to position, with the following

```
`<a class="icon" id="guy-in-mri-or-washing-machine" xlink:href="#">
<g transform="translate(170,360)">
<g transform="scale(1.25)">
<g transform="translate(-170,-360)">
<path d="M197.3` etc
```

You still need to add the hover of course, but at least it works in all browsers