# Circle radius set in CSS, how to get value through JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to style a circle showing the progress percent as the circumference. I want to get the radius in JS but style the circle in CSS.
The function I use to do this is `setPercent`. It reads the radius of the circle by selecting the radius element and getting the radius measures from there.

This is the code that works:

```js
const fn = function() {
  let circle = document.querySelector('circle.percent')
  debugger
  let radius = circle.r.baseVal.value
  let circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius
  circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`


  this.setPercent = function(percent) {
    circle.style.strokeDashoffset = (100 - percent) / 100 * circumference
  }
}
setTimeout(fn, 1)
```

```css
:root {
  --back-ground: #30384a;
  --neutral-circle-border: #656c79;
  --completed-color: #67ed8b;
  background: var(--back-ground)
}

div.normal_square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

svg.progress-ring {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

svg.progress-ring circle {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: black;
  cx: 50%;
  cy: 50%;
  r: 40%;
}

svg.progress-ring circle.percent {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

svg.progress-ring circle.background {
  stroke: var(--neutral-circle-border)
}
```

```html
<div margin="0 auto">
  <svg class="progress-ring" width="200px" height="200px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle class="background"/>
      <circle class="percent" fill="transparent" stroke-width="6" stroke="black" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="40%" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

However, when I remove that `r="40%"` from my code, I can't get the radius measured from `circle.r...`. Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: For now you can't change the circle's radius in CSS. Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255631/style-svg-circle-with-css

Answer (score 0):

Use [`window.getComputedStyle(element)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to retrieve the value instead.

Currently you're retrieving the property value from the element reference, when you remove the property there's nothing left to retrieve.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that too but the problem is that returns "40%" not the actual pixels, unlike the other method. I don't understand why this happens, because the circle still exists and it has a radius, it makes sense to be able to get that through element properties.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same problem. This worked:

```js
let radius = circle.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2;
```

Seems silly to have to do this though. Hopefully someone posts a better way.